# Modify the tabs in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I would like to modify the disposition of some of the tabs in Lightning Experience in the Sales App. Here is what i would like to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Lightning, go to ⚙ (Gear), Setup Home > Apps > App Manager > Sales (Developer Name: LightningSales), ▼ (Arrow Dropdown) Edit, select the SELECT ITEMS tab, and then you can move items to the left to remove them, to the right to add them, and up or down to choose the order from left to right (topmost item will appear on the left, bottommost on the right).

Answer (score 4):

> Navigate to, Setup -> Apps --> App Manager --> Sales App (from list of apps)

Clicking on edit you will see the `Selected Tabs` and `Available tabs`.

You can make a choice of disposition.

> Please note that `Home` must the first tab and cannot be removed.

Comment: Home can now be moved and removed in Lightning Apps.