# How do I view my custom object records in the UI?

Tags: rest-api

I created a custom object and used the REST API to create new records of that type. (requests were successful, no errors)
How can I view them in the UI?

It seems like such a basic thing to do yet I've been searching for an answer for the past 30 minutes and couldn't find anything.

I'm trying to do it using the admin user using the Lightning UI of the Sales app.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details about the issue and what you've already tried to solve it. If you're receiving a specific error message, include it in full. Are you accessing records via the REST API or the UI, and have you confirmed that the appropriate permissions are in place?

Comment: Google "creating object tab" - that will allow you to view records through the UI in SFDC. You can also use workbench (also google) to view them

Comment: I added more details to my post. 
I did create a new custom object tab, now how can i view it?

Comment: Answer is here
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/147454/3716

Comment: Also thanks for "workbench", nice tool! (i'm new to SalesForce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/147454/3716

> Navigate to, Setup -> Apps --> App Manager --> Sales App (from list of
>   apps)

Clicking on edit you will see the Selected Tabs and Available tabs.

Here you can add a new tab to Sales App.

Also when you are creating a new tab you are prompted if you want to add it to standard Sales app.

Comment: I can't see the Selected Tabs and Available Tabs, does it exist for Lightning?

Comment: I noticed it exists only in Classic, and even then, my custom tab isn't in the Available Tabs list.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you System Administrator? Did you click on edit button and select Items submenu?

Comment: Ok i found the tab, thanks! And sorry for all of the misunderstandings, i'm new to SalesForce, appreciate the help!

Comment: Good. I was going to shot a video describing how to search for it

Comment: Haha wow that would have been awesome, thanks for the good intentions :)